# Unity3d APK error while upload to google play

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, apk

I have created an APK using Unity but cannot upload it onto GooglePlay because it isn't assigned. I saw many pages on how can I solve it using Unity, but I am using a Mac.

I tried changing `.apk` to `.zip` and then changing the parameters in `.xml` (manifest) accordingly, but GooglePlay shows:

> You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a
>   zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.

Please help.

Comment: REPATE: i have only .apk, i have deleted the project files of unity3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With command-lines, you can sign(with [jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) from the java-jdk) and align(with [zipalign](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html) from the android-SDK).

- Sign:
  `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name`
- Align:
  `zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-unaligned.apk your_project_name.apk`

Having the error: ***unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size ...*** means that the apk is already signed, you should:

- Verify that it's not signed with the debug-key:
  `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk`.
- Remove the debug-signature if needed:
  `zip -d foo.apk META-INF/\*`

Comment: i have to put the apk in a specific dir?

Comment: it gives me an error: jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: /Users/Painkiller/my-release-key.keystore (No such file or directory

Comment: im trying to use this guide: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: _my-release-key.keystore_ should be the keystore containing your release-key. You can create one, if it's not already done: `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Comment: yas, i have created the kaystore, now, have i to put the apk in spacific di to signed it with jarsigner??

Comment: You don't have to move the apk to sign it. Just adapt the command with the absolute path of the apk.

Comment: where in osx i can see the path of a file??

Comment: For the path, you can drag&drop the file in the command-line-interface, and you'll have the full-path. So with the full-paths your command could look like this `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore /Users/Painkiller/my-release-key.keystore  /Users/Painkiller/Unity/my_application.apk -alias alias_name`

Comment: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 4710 but got 4759 bytes)

Comment: You apk is probably already signed. To verify, run `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk`

Comment: ok: Warning: 
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2045-07-17) or after any future revocation date.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the CA-chain warning(self-signed certificate), it's "normal". Check that the apk wasn't signed with the debug-key, the CN(common-name) in the _jarsigner -verify ..._ output holds that information. If needed you can remove the signature with `zip -d foo.apk META-INF/\*` and sign with the correct key. You cannot release with the debug-key.

Comment: yes. But you have to resign with your release.keystore.